# How to access to URL parameter inside of get_queryset in Django?

Tags: python, django

Supposing, I've got a URL pattern like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^mylist/(?P<offset>\d+)/$', MylistView.as_view(), name='mylist'),
    ...
]
```

My view class:

```
class MylistView(ListView):
    template_name = 'mylist.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        offset = ... # What should I type here?
        entries = models.MylistEntry.all()[offset:offset+10]
        return entries
```

How do I access to the URL parameter `offset` within the method `get_queryset`? I've checked the variables `args` and `kwargs` are empty.

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use self of get_queryset method for fetch url parameter

```
 self.kwargs.get('offset')
```